# Principled Method for Reweighting Labels Based on Labeler Consistency?

Tags: agreement-statistics, weighted-mean, rating, labeling

I have a large dataset where each datum has been labeled by multiple raters, and each rater has labeled multiple datums. Rather than assigning to each datum the naive average of all of the labels assigned to it by different raters, I thought it would be better to take a weighted average according to some measure of each rater's "reliability".

As a proxy for "reliability" I'm planning on using some measure of how often a given rater agrees with other raters, but am wondering how best to:

1. Quantify this consistency of rater agreement
2. Transform these consistency values into label weightings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the [Concordance Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) does what I need. For anyone else with a similar question, I recommend the wikipedia page on [Inter-rater Reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability).